# How to update stock level after 'order' has been made?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am practicing using databases in python with sqlite3. I am creating a stock management system for a shop and I have a product table with fields: ProductID, Name, StockLevel.

I am struggling to update the stock level when a purchase is made. So the stock level for a specific product should be subtracted by the number ordered.

My code:

```
def update_stock(product,no_bought):
    with sqlite3.connect("shop.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "UPDATE Product SET StockLevel = StockLevel - %s WHERE Name = %s" 
        cursor.execute(sql, (no_bought, product))
        db.commit()

product = input("What product has been bought: ")
no_bought = input("How much has been bought: ")
update_stock(product,no_bought)
```

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Why is it giving this error?

Comment: You can't implement both solutions. You're current edit, shows using the method `format` to replace the placeholders. Then you still pass the variables to `cursor.execute` as though there are still place holders. There aren't. You can either pass the string _with placeholders_ to `cursor,execute` or you can replace them first and pass the complete string alone.

Comment: TheHerk I have corrected it but the error still appears

Comment: No, you implemented both. I'll fix my answer after alecxe reminded me about sql safety in this method.

Comment: I have removed my answer. In spite of correctly covering string formatting here, @alecxe correctly pointed out that the `execute` method is much safer for replacement. Pass your string with placeholders (i.e. `{}`, `{varname}`, or `%s`), then pass the replacement tuple or dictionary as `params` argument to `execute`.

Comment: In this case, simply remove ` % (no_bought,product)` from the end of the `sql` string declaration.

Comment: Doesn't SQLite only support `?` as the placeholder?

Comment: Dan D. Thanks!!

Comment: Good catch @DanD. Indeed. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two placeholders for both of your variables and properly *parameterize your query* (beware of [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!):

```
sql = """
    UPDATE  
        Product 
    SET 
        StockLevel = StockLevel - ?
    WHERE 
        Name = ?
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (no_bought, product))
```

Notice how query parameters are passed to `execute()` separately and how we have 2 placeholders in the query itself.

Comment: Having made those changes, another error has occurred as seen in the post

Comment: alecxe change `%s` to `?`

Answer (score 1):

Use `?` as your placeholder based on the documentation for [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

```
def update_stock(product, no_bought):
    with sqlite3.connect("shop.db") as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql = "UPDATE Product SET StockLevel = StockLevel - ? WHERE Name = ?"
        cursor.execute(sql, (no_bought, product))
        db.commit()
product = input("What product has been bought: ")
no_bought = input("How much has been bought: ")
update_stock(product,no_bought)
```

Comment: Reason for the downvote: you are supporting OP's efforts to have code vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Right you are. I forgot the importance of using the library for the replacement. I'll update.

Comment: I have updated this, based on my oversight that you should do string formatting. Let the library do it for safety (thank you @alecxe). Also, since it is sqlite, it required `?` for placeholder.